# Vertical offset when displaying an image with wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, sizer

Here is how we can display an image in a wxPython frame.

[image]

```
import wx

class Viewer(wx.App):
    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)
        self.frame = wx.Frame(None, title='Viewer')
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self.frame)
        self.imageCtrl = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.BitmapFromImage(wx.EmptyImage(800,600)))
        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.imageCtrl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.onView('0.png')
        self.panel.Layout()        
        self.frame.Show()

    def onView(self, filename):
        img = wx.Image(filename, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
        self.panel.Refresh()
        self.mainSizer.Fit(self.frame)
        
Viewer().MainLoop()
```

If the test image has large dimensions, e.g. 912 x 3616 (here is the [0.png](http://gget.it/x6xkegzy/0.png) I used), **I would like to set a vertical offset**, i.e. **the upper corner of the frame should not be (0,0) of the image but (0,500)** i.e. a 500px vertical offset.

**How to set a vertical offset to an image with wxPython?**

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to truncate the image, the most straightforward thing is to just do it, i.e. create a new image using `wxImage::GetSubImage()` with the region starting at (0, 500).

More usually, you would use a scrolled window and then you could scroll it by 500 vertically initially, but still allow the user to scroll back to the origin.

It is also possible to use scroll window without scrollbars, but this seems rather pointless.

Comment: I tried by cropping it (this is linked to keyboard keys like DOWN, UP, etc.) but then on each repaint `self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))` there is flicker. Do you have an idea how to avoid this flicker?

Comment: If you want to scroll it with the keys, use a scrolled window. In any case, definitely do not use `wxStaticBitmap` with big images, especially if you need to change them, but rather draw them yourself. As mentioned in the documentation, `wxStaticBitmap` is meant for small icons in the dialogs, not general purpose image display.

Comment: Thanks @VZ. Would you have some code example to show how I shoud do it?

Comment: You can find example of using scrolled windows in the wxWidgets `scroll` sample, but they're in C++, not Python. I expect wxPython demo contains an example using it too.